# Open Textmate with drawer hidden?

Tags: macos, mac, textmate

When I open a folder with textmate, either from finder, quicksilver, or the shell addon (mate), the project drawer pops up. Is there a way this can be hidden by default?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a setting for not showing the drawer by default.

If you can live without the drawer, you can make it as small as possible:

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakProjectDrawerWidth -int 1
```

Which will leave you with a very small (but still slightly visible) drawer (can't post images yet). That last remnant would be even less noticeable if you install Ciarán Walsh’s [ProjectPlus](http://ciaranwal.sh/projectplus) plugin.

The neatest solution would be to take the [source code](https://github.com/rsence/projectplus) of ProjectPlus, and add the desired behaviour.

Comment: How do I put it back to the default value if I don't like your change? Just want to know before I try it.

Comment: defaults delete com.macromates.textmate OakProjectDrawerWidth

Comment: just tested and this seems to work very well. the note about setting it back to default also works great. thanks!